# How to pass a different props to a specific children?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am using React.cloneElement to pass props to children. But this will also send same props to those chilren who do not need a specific prop. That means some children getting unecessary props.

So, is it OK if those children get those props but do not use them ?

How would I pass an specific prop to a specific child ?

Comment: Maybe attach some code.

Comment: It is fine if children don't use all of their props afaik.

Comment: Somebody said I should not use React.CloneElement. It mau cause problems. Any comment on this ?